# PyCharm says unfilled parameters even though all parameters are optional

Tags: python, parameters, pycharm, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a function which should receive another function as an argument. I defined that parameter annotation as:

```py
input_function: Callable[
    [
        Optional[InputType],
        Optional[Sequence[str]],
        Optional[bool]
    ],
    Awaitable[str]
] = func
```

My `func` function, meanwhile, is defined like so:

```py
async def func(input_type: InputType = None, formats: Sequence[str] = (), *, hide: bool = False) -> str: ...
```

The function signature and parameter annotation should be the same. However, when I call that function with only one parameter (as all of the parameters are optional), PyCharm says that there are unfilled parameters:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Define the signature as a `Protocol` with `__call__`, not a `Callable`.

```py
from typing import Protocol


class InputFunction(Protocol):
    async def __call__(self, input_type: InputType = None, formats: Sequence[str] = (), *, hide: bool = False) -> str: ...

input_function: InputFunction = func
```

---

The `Callable` type can only express a limited kind of signatures: Explicit positional parameters such as `Callable[[A, B], R]` or arbitrary parameters such as `Callable[..., R]`. Typing one of its parameter as `Optional[T]` means it must be "a `T` or `None`", not that it can be omitted.

In contrast, a `Protocol`'s `__call__` method allows to define the signature using regular definition syntax, including all of its features such as default values.

> #### [Callback Protocols](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols)
>
> Protocols can be used to define flexible callback types that are hard (or even impossible) to express using the `Callable[...]` syntax, such as variadic, overloaded, and complex generic callbacks. They are defined with a special `__call__` member:

While a `Protocol` is a class, it matches structurally: defining it with just a `__call__` method merely encodes "callable object of same signature", and functions of same signature satisfy this as well.

Note that the `self` parameter is required on the `__call__` definition, but not used to check whether signatures match.

Comment: It seems like you implemented `func` instead of `__call__`. Is that a mistake or that’s how it is supposed to be?

Comment: @Jonathan1609 Ooops. That was a mistake indeed. Fixed.

Comment: Ok cool, i will mark this answer as soon as i get to the computer. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't work as I don't want PyCharm to tell the end user that his function should be an instance of `InputFunction`. I want Pycharm to tell him to use a function which fits the signature in `__call__`. photo: https://imgur.com/p969BRC.png

Comment: can you please look at it and see what's wrong?

Answer (score -1):

[The documentation for typing.Optional](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typing#typing.Optional) states:

> Note that this is not the same concept as an optional argument, which is one that has a default.

And [the documentation for typing.Callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typing#typing.Callable) states:

> There is no syntax to indicate optional or keyword arguments

As such, it is not possible to accurately define the type of the function the way you want it.

Comment: Your first point is correct, your second is not. You're correct to point out that `typing.Optional` does not mean what OP seems to think it does, and that's very useful information. Unfortunately, your second point is incorrect — it *is* possible to accurately define functions indicating optional or keyword arguments. The way to do that is by using a callback protocol, as @MisterMiyagi says in his answer and as is advised by the MyPy documentation https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols